# Using Docker and Vagrant with Node and Express

Tags: node.js, vagrant, docker

So before I start, I'm new to this and since I learn best when I give myself a project I wanted to user Vagrant and Docker to make a simple Node and Express server with a shared folder outside of the actual container. I followed a tutorial which explained similar things with nginx and php (which worked) so please if the question is not very well structured or my English isn't perfect let me know!

As I said I wanted to practice Docker a bit (I recently started working with it) and learn Vagrant. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm

RUN cd /home
RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install -g express-generator
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN express projekt
RUN cd projekt && npm install
VOLUME ["/home/projekt/"]

EXPOSE 3000
RUN DEBUG=projekt:* /home/projekt/bin/www
```

Also the `projekt` is spelled like that intentionally since it's in my language. So I basically wanted to install node and npm. Then I wanted to generate Express project and also sym linked node and nodejs. Now the problem with this is that the last command fails. It says:

`/bin/sh: 1: /home/projekt/bin/www: not found`

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "./www", "/home/projekt"   # Sync'd folder
  config.ssh.port = "22"
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "./Docker" # specifies the path to the Dockerfile
    d.ports = [ '80:3000' ]  # Forwards port 8080 from the host to the Docker Container port 80
  end
end
```

This is how my root project folder looks:

```
.
├── Docker
│   └── Dockerfile
├── Vagrantfile
└── www

2 directories, 2 files
```

Also if this question is not suitable for this StackExchange could you please direct me where I could ask this!

Comment: Can you list the contents of `www` as well? Is `/home/projekt/bin/www` supposed to be a script or binary in the container? I don't see where you are adding this script or binary to the container.